# Custom Type? If we can say that

Tags: java

I am a bit new to java, I learnt some stuff about it but I have a question.
I am currently making a Minecraft plugin but It doesen't matter. (I think)
How can I make it so I have a custom type? Sorry, I can't really explain it. I'll show you what I mean.

```
// I have a static void for getting items
public static void(CustomItemTypes type) {
    // Do Stuff
}

// So I have that "CustomItemTypes" thing, I want to make a custom thing of that type. 
// So like not "String" or "Integer" but my custom type. Sorry I am really bad at
// explaining stuff. :/
```

How could I do that? Thank you for your answers! <3

Comment: What you are asking about is one of the most basic concepts in Java and object oriented programming in general, so I suggest you to get some book or tutorial about programming in Java and start from there. Its best to learn from simple examples instead of starting with big idea and giving up very soon just because you constantly face something you don't know.

Comment: It depends on how `CustomItemTypes` is defined. Maybe `new CustomItemTypes(someParams)`, or something along the lines of `CustomItemTypes.create(someParams)`, or you might even want to call a method of another class to retrieve your instance of `CustomItemTypes`. In most cases you'll want to read the javadoc of the class to determine how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is generics

```
public class test{
   public static void(CustomItemTypes<YourCustomType> type) {
   }
}

public class CustomItemTypes<T>{

}
```